# Weighted Mean in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time-series data with different lengths - a,b,c,d,e

```
 #printing a
 Time Series:
  Start = 1
  End = 42
  Frequency = 1
  [1] 60 
 
#printing b
Time Series:
  Start = 1
  End = 42
  Frequency = 1
  [1] 50 70  
 
#printing c
Time Series:
  Start = 1
  End = 42
  Frequency = 1
  [1] 40 70 100

 #and so on
```

I am trying to get the mean of elements in all lists:
#since there are 5 values available for 1st element

```
mean1 <- a[1]+b[1]+c[1]+d[1]+e[1] / 5 

 #since there are 4 values available for 2nd element

mean2<-  b[2]+c[2]+d[2]+e[2] / 4

#next divide by 3 and 2...1

mean3<- c[3]+d[3]+e[3] / 3 and so on...
```

I need the mean of these values so that I can make a weighted mean for each element for further processing.
Can anyone give suggestion on what to do to obtain the weighted mean from this data??

Comment: u mean the dummy data?

Comment: @akrun, I think its solved now. There was an ')'

Comment: its a small part of a big code. many packages were loaded for the initial analysis

Comment: some structure in the code requires the package to be loaded.  Without knowing which package, not clear

Comment: @akrun I checked the dummy data now. Some errors in the data are discarded and the variables are loading now. Please check once again with your IDE

Comment: I still get errors `b <- list(dummy = structure(c(-100.234 ,123.55), .Tsp = c(183.142857142857, 183.285714285714, 7), class = "ts"))
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"`

Comment: It is actually running for me. Try loading packeges - forecast,future
$dummy
Time Series:
Start = c(183, 2) 
End = c(183, 3) 
Frequency = 7 
[1] -100.234  123.550

Comment: Is it because you have `a <- list(list(du` instead of `a <- list(dummy`

Comment: No, Please check now. Sorry again for the errors. Its working fine now @akrun

Comment: Do you want `lst1 <- lapply(mget(letters[1:5]), unlist); rowMeans(sapply(lst1, "length<-", max(lengths(lst1))), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: The `1/5(` part is not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247529/discussion-between-bella-pa-and-akrun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get the objects in a `list`, then get the `mean` from the `list` and do the weighted calculation

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(letters[1:5]), unlist)
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx)
(1/mx) * (rowSums(mapply(`*`, lst2,  
     rowMeans(simplify2array(lst2), na.rm = TRUE)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
l <- c(a,b,c,d,e)

tapply(unlist(l), sequence(lengths(l)), mean)
        1         2         3         4         5 
 6923.783 -2462.537 16402.663    62.005   432.800
```

Comment: I get this error - Error in tapply(unlist(my_list), sequence(lengths(my_list)), mean) : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: @bella_pa I just used the code the way you gave it. THis time round I used `c(a,b,c,d,e)` instead of `list(a,b,c,d,e)` and used the same code and provided the result